# Is it possible to edit jobs & triggers in Quartz.NET

Tags: quartz.net

Is it possible to edit already running job's name, group or a trigger's schedule information in Quartz.NET scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two fields combined make up the primary key on the database.  You cannot change them via the Quartz API.

If you're using the XML file, you can change the names and restart.

Comment: You can add and remove triggers to a job.  Beware of removing the last trigger associated with a job.  If the job isn't "durable", it can get removed from the system when it doesn't have a trigger.

Comment: My question is not reg. adding and removing triggers, it's about editing the properties of an existing trigger that is linked with a job, is that possible? (I'm using AdoJobStore)

Comment: You can't change them through the API.  If you really need them changed, you could update the records in the database.  I would delete and re-add the job with the new values.